# Is there a CodeIgniter function that helps us determine the width and height of an image?

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is a core PHP function called `getimagesize()` that helps us determine the width and height of an image. I was wondering is there a CodeIgniter function that helps us do the same? Or should we refer `getimagesize()` itself to get the width and height of an image in CodeIgniter.

Comment: if there is a php native function - you should use it - on the other hand Codeigniter delivers an image manipulation class (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=image) - so if you want to do something with your image - it probably would help you - otherwise stick to the native functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Codeigniter function to get the height and width of an image. You can use the following to get `Height` and `Width` of the image.

```
$data = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];
```